# How do I incorporate a Double Moving Average in straight SQL in a single query?

Tags: sql, ms-access

EDIT: I need to do this in ACCESS.

I am an SQL virgin and would greatly appreciate any magical assistance!

For a simple 12 month forecast, I am utilizing a **12 month Double Moving Average**. 
I have managed to pull the Single Moving Average through Query 1 (below). 
Based on the table created by Query 1, I have written another query (Query 2) to get the Double Moving Average.

> As such, my current process requires two queries. My efforts so far to combine these two steps into a single query have not been successful.

My Question: Is there any way to calculate Double Moving Average in a single query?

QUERY 1 - For Single Moving Average:

```
    SELECT A.*, IIf([A].[VOL]>0,
    (SELECT AVG(B.[VOL])
    FROM [Turnover] as B
    WHERE (B.Code = A.Code) AND (B.YM Between A.YM - 1  AND A.YM - ([12] * 31))),
    (SELECT AVG(B.[VOL])
    FROM [Turnover] as B
    WHERE (B.Code = A.Code) AND (B.YM Between Now() - 31  AND A.YM - ([12] * 31)))) AS [Mvg Avg 1],  
    INTO [Model 12m]
    FROM [Turnover] AS A;
```

QUERY 2 - Double Moving Average (currently this refers to QUERY 1):

```
    SELECT A.*, IIf([A].[Mvg Avg 1]>0,(SELECT AVG(B.[Mvg Avg 1])
    FROM [Model 12m] as B
    WHERE (B.Code = A.Code) AND (B.YM Between A.YM - 1  AND A.YM - ([12] * 31))),(SELECT AVG(B.[Mvg Avg 1])
    FROM [Model 12m] as B
    WHERE (B.Code = A.Code) AND (B.YM Between Now() - 31  AND A.YM - ([12] * 31)))) AS [2 Mvg Avg],
    INTO [Model 12m - 2MA]
    FROM [Model 12m] AS A;
```

Comment: Which RDBMS?  And do you ***really*** need to do this in SQL rather than in your application?  *(Unless you have an RDBMS that implements `LAG()`, these queries tend to be quite inefficient in SQL.)*

Comment: @Dems: actually a moving average is quite easy using something like `avg(x) over (order by some_col rows between current row and 12 preceding)`, no need for `lag()`. But SQL Server (which is obviously used here) does not support

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - If `rows between current row and 5 preceding` is supported then that *is* `LAG()` *functionally* being supported.  *(`5 preceding` being the functionality required.)*  And if no `LAG()` *functionality* is supported, then `rows between current row and 5 preceding` implicitily isn't supported.  It's symantics, I was just looking for a quick way of describing to the OP how to identify *functionality* to determine if the RDBMS is moving-average-fiendly.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name SQL Server supports this in 2012, although you need to specify `between 3 preceding and current row` http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/190bf/4

Comment: To clarify, I am doing this in ACCESS. Unfortunately, I will not be able to use SQL Server.

Comment: Do you have access to a calendar table?  A simple table with one row per date, columns for the first day of the week, month, year, and a flag whether it is a business day or not, will help tremendously.  Your current queries, using (12 * 31) to simulate a year, is not going to provide accurate results in Access or any other DBMS.

Comment: I happened across your question because it had votes but no upvoted answer. If you're still interested in an answer, I might be able to help. But I don't want to create the test data. If you'll provide sample data for the `Turnover` table and the expected results, I think I can show you how to compute both results in a single query that references `Turnover` only once. I don't have access to Access; it will need to support `CASE` in the `SELECT` statement.

Answer (score 1):

> My Question: Is there any way to calculate Double Moving Average in a
>   single query?

Since you're using Microsoft Access, there should be no need to do that. Save the first query as a new query. (For people who don't use MS Access, saving the SQL statement as a new query is equivalent to the SQL statement `CREATE VIEW ...`.)  Then use the second query as-is, or save it as *another* new query.

MS Access is *really* good at optimizing queries built on queries (views built on views).